# undefined not assignable issue in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I have an interface Employee:

```
export interface Employee {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

I am trying to push elements of Type Employee into an array as below:

```
  let allEmployees: Employee[] = [];
  allEmployees = emp.data?.map((employee) => {
    return { firstName: employee.firstName, lastName: employee.lastName }
  });
```

I am getting the following typescript compile time error:

```
type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Employee[]'
```

I have used .map function to return final value of the array. How do I resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Please consider editing the code in the question to constitute a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) so others can see the issue for themselves.  The type of `emp` is important here. I presume its `data` property might itself be `undefined`, and therefore the optional chaining operator `emp.data?.map()` will possibly set `allEmployees` to `undefined` without ever running `map()`. Also, I don't see you trying to push any elements; instead you're trying to reassign `allEmployees`.  Do you want to try to `push()` instead?

Comment: The push method did work. But I wanted to reuse the .map function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `emp.data?` possibly returns `void 0` as well. That's why you don't have to use `proposal-optional-chaining`, just check like below:

```
allEmployees = emp.data ? emp.data.map((employee) => {
  return { firstName: employee.firstName, lastName: employee.lastName }
}) : [];
```

Answer (score 1):

`?` in `emp.data?` means `data` is optional and might not exist in `emp`, which tells typescript not to go through the chained function, i.e `map`. So your assignment can return `undefined` or `Employee[]`, which cannot be assigned to `allEmployees`.

Comment: One of many possible fixes: `let allEmployes = (emp.data ?? []).map(/*...*/);`